# How to systematically check whether given Yang-Mills field has some symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

It is known that there exist solutions to Yang Mills equations which don't have (for example) rotational symmetry but they are spherically symmetric in generalized sense: effect of rotation can be undone by gauge transformation. Neat example is provided by 't Hooft Polyakov monopole. Natural question arises: how to characterize this situation? I have managed to show that in this case for $A$-gauge field, $\psi$-matter field, $X$ - vector field generating desired symmetry flow there exists Lie-algebra valued function $\epsilon$ such that $$L_X A = D \epsilon,$$ $$L_X \psi = -i \epsilon \psi,$$
where $D$ is gauge covariant derivative and $L$ is Lie derivative. However, this condition is not so simple to check or solve in general. Do you know of simpler or more detailed characterization?

Remark: situation is trivial in abelian case. Here F is gauge invariant and the relevant condition is $L_X F =0.$